# Changing the data in the service doesn't work properly with $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following service in angular:

```
myModule.factory("myService", function(){
   return {
      data: [],

      updateData: function(data){
         this.data = data;
      }
   }
});
```

I also have a directive and a controller which uses the service:

```
myModule.controller("myController", ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    this.directiveOptions = {data: myService.data, someOtherData: null};
});

 myModule.directive("myDirective", function(){
     return {
            scope: {
                options: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.$watch('options.data', function(newData){
                    alert("data was changed");
                });
            }
        };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <my-directive options="ctrl.directiveOptions"></my-directive>
</div>
```

In some point in the application I call "updateData" (of the service). The watch is being called but the newData I'm getting is the old data.

I can think of an explanation why the watch should not work at all, but can't explain its current behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: did you happen to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The exlpanation is quite simple, let's work it out step-by-step:

1. At first the `myService.data` array is created. Let's call this array A1.
2. Then the controller is created and sets `this.directiveOptions.data = myService.data = A1`.
3. Then `myService.updateData()` gets called and the `myService.data` array receives a new value, A2.

See the problem?

`this.directiveOptions.data` is *still* "pointing" (in C parlance) to A1. It has no way of knowing that the source, form where it actually received A1 changed.

Two solutions that I can think of:

1. `myService.updateData()` should update the same array, e.g. truncate and refill it with the new data as:

   ```
   updateData: function(data){
       this.data.length = 0;
       for( var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
           this.data[i] = data[i];
       }
   }
   ```
2. `$watch(myService.data)` in the controller and act accordingly:

   ```
   // inside the controller
   var self = this;
   $scope.$watch(
       function() { return myService.data; },
       function(newval) {
           self.directiveOptions.data = newval;
       }
   );
   ```

Comment: That's what I thought and I actually have the same solution as you suggested. I just wasn't sure it's a good solution. It feels a little bit of a hack

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may revolve around doing a deep watch, if the data is an array, which could be handled  a couple ways:

```
scope.$watch('options.data', function(newData){
                    alert("data was changed");
                }, true); <--passing in true calls deep watches
```

Or better watch the data collection using $watchCollection